# How to jump to links and open it in Mutt

Tags: mutt

I just started using Mutt. How can I jump to a link and next link and so on in Mutt? And how to open in in w3m?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mutt doesn't have the ability to follow links itself, but you can have Mutt run some external tools that will do so.

One is [urlview](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/urlview1.html). You can execute it while viewing an HTML message in Mutt's pager by typing Ctrl-B, which is bound by default to a macro that runs `urlview`. That will display a menu of the links in the message, allowing you to jump from there to a link's target using your preferred browser.

I prefer to use `w3m` for that purpose because it shows the links in the context of the message, so I have this macro defined in my muttrc:

```
macro index,pager \cB ": unset wait_key; set pipe_decode\n|w3m\n: set wait_key; unset pipe_decode\n" "call w3m to extract URLs out of a message"
```

Because this macro sends plain text rather than HTML to `w3m`, you have to tell `w3m` to convert anything that looks like a link to an actual link by typing `:`.

If the message is HTML, or has an HTML part, you can view that part using `w3m` instead of Mutt's pager by using the attachment menu, bound to `v` by default.  If your mailcap file is configured properly, selecting the HTML part of the message in that menu and hitting `Enter` will launch `w3m` to display the message. Then you can follow links as you normally do when browsing with `w3m`.

By a properly-configured mailcap file, I mean one containing a line like this:

```
text/html; w3m %s; nametemplate=%s.html
```

This explanation, along with more about using Mutt, can be found [here](http://www.spocom.com/users/gjohnson/mutt/#w3m) and [here](http://www.spocom.com/users/gjohnson/mutt/#html).